# Three.js/WebGL scale to fixed dimensions

Tags: webgl, three.js

I have certain Plane Geometries which might be of any dimension.

I have to scale them to a particular dimension (say 1024x768 or 768x1024)

Three.js offers scaling through the Geometry.scale object. This works great if you know what the initial height/width is, since I can just do:

```
obj.scale.x = finalWidth/initialWidth;
obj.scale.y = finalHeight/initialHeight;
```

But there's no object that will return the Geometry Height and Width (i.e. initialWidth and initialHeight) (Correct me if I am wrong here).

So is there any way to scale a geometry to a particular dimension without knowing the initial dimensions?

P.S. You could ask how I am building the object in the first place when I don't know the initial dimensions. I do, of course, know the initial dimensions but that is in another far far away part of the framework I am building and would like to avoid keeping track of the dimensions throughout if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say is true. You could try

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
```

The dimensions can then be computed from `geometry.boundingBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. To complete the solution:

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
```

After computeBoundingBox is called, the dimensions can be read from geometry.boundingBox

```
width = geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x
height = geometry.boundingBox.max.y - geometry.boundingBox.min.y
depth = geometry.boundingBox.max.z - geometry.boundingBox.min.z
```